# How can I change Media items in Android MediaBrowserServiceCompat

Tags: android, android-auto, mediabrowserservicecompat

I am making an Android Auto based media player.  I really have one page of media that can be played, but sometimes the titles of these items change.  Lets say the first item says 'news of the hour for 12pm' and then it changes to 'news of the hour for 1p'.

onGetRoot is called, then I populate my media items in onLoadChildren.  I make  ArrayList at the time of launch, but these items can change.

How do I programmatically alter the MediaItem objects already loaded into the UI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly what the [`notifyChildrenChanged()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/media/MediaBrowserServiceCompat#notifychildrenchanged) method on `MediaBrowserServiceCompat` is for - calling that will invalidate the data returned by `onLoadChildren` and cause the system to call `onLoadChildren` again to retrieve your updated data.

Comment: I believe this is the solution, and it seems to have worked for me.  Thanks!